# How do I use an external log4j.xml configuration file using spring boot?

Tags: spring, logging, log4j

I created a spring boot project and wanted to use an external log4j.xml configuration file with my jar.  The command line I'm using is this:

```
java -Dlog4j.debug -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/tmp/log4j.xml -jar /tmp/project.jar
```

From looking at the debug, it looks like it actually loads the log4j.xml correctly, but shortly after it loads the log4j.xml, it then loads the log4j.properties inside the spring-boot jar file, which overrides my log4j.xml.  Is there a way to ignore the log4j.properties from within the spring-boot jar file?

```
log4j: Using URL [file:/tmp/log4j.xml] for automatic log4j configuration.
log4j: Preferred configurator class: org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator
log4j: System property is :null
log4j: Standard DocumentBuilderFactory search succeded.
log4j: DocumentBuilderFactory is: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
log4j: debug attribute= "null".
log4j: Ignoring debug attribute.
log4j: reset attribute= "false".
log4j: Threshold ="null".
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [com.test] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for com.test is  [trace].
log4j: com.test level set to TRACE
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [org.springframework.core] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for org.springframework.core is  [info].
log4j: org.springframework.core level set to INFO
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [org.springframework.beans] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for org.springframework.beans is  [info].
log4j: org.springframework.beans level set to INFO
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [org.springframework.context] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for org.springframework.context is  [info].
log4j: org.springframework.context level set to INFO
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [org.springframework.web] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for org.springframework.web is  [info].
log4j: org.springframework.web level set to INFO
log4j: Level value for root is  [warn].
log4j: root level set to WARN
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender]
log4j: Setting property [file] to [/var/log/app/app.log].
log4j: Setting property [maxFileSize] to [5000KB].
log4j: Setting property [maxBackupIndex] to [5].
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZ} %-5.5p [%-15.15t][%30.30c{2}#%17.17M]: %m%n].
log4j: setFile called: /var/log/app/app.log, true
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Adding appender named [R] to category [root].
log4j: Reading configuration from URL jar:file:/tmp/project.jar!/lib/spring-boot-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/boot/logging/log4j/log4j.properties
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[INFO, CONSOLE].
log4j: Level token is [INFO].
log4j: Category root set to INFO
log4j: Parsing appender named "CONSOLE".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "CONSOLE".
```

Comment: have a look here => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039249/disable-automatic-logging-configuration-in-spring-boot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spring boot log4j file external to jar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32356997/spring-boot-log4j-file-external-to-jar)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I know it's been a while, but I just came across this very same problem, so maybe I can help.

First of all, make sure the external file has a **different** name than the internal `log4j.xml`. As an example we will name it `log4j-tmp.xml`.
Now in addition to `log4j.configuration` you just have to define `logging.config` in your command line:

```
java -Dlog4j.debug -Dlogging.config=file:/tmp/log4j-tmp.xml -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/tmp/log4j-tmp.xml -jar /tmp/project.jar
```

You could also copy your `application.properties` outside of your jar (Spring Boot will search for external config files and use them instead of the jar's) and define `logging.config=path/to/log4j-tmp.xml` in it, but there's no point in duplicating your whole config file just for one property when you can add it via command line.

Comment: Thanks for this, it was driving me mad not getting this to work :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually Walen has the answer:

instead of:

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/tmp/log4j.xml
```

you should use:

```
-Dlogging.config=/tmp/log4j.xml
```

so the command is:

```
java -Dlog4j.debug -Dlogging.config=file:/tmp/log4j.xml -jar /tmp/project.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

For Spring Boot you can put

`logging.config=${user.home}/projectName/log4j.xml`

to src/main/resources/application.properties file in your project.

Where ${user.home} is wildcard. In Linux it directs to /home/user/ and in windows environment to C:\Users\user directories. This conf parameter works for Spring Boot default logger Logback as well.

Answer (score -1):

in SpringBootServletInitializer  you can have

@PropertySource(value="file:${YOUR JVM ARGS OF PROP DIR}application.properties")

The above will load the application properties to environment.

Define a property in application.properties

logging.config.file={YOUR PATH TO XML CONFIG}/MyLog4jCnfg.xml

You can use @Value to get the respective properties.
Note that you cannot access these properties in configure() method.

You need to use a @PostConstruct  initAfterStartup()  to access your

@Value(logging.config.file)