# spring boot log4j file external to jar?

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-boot

how to pass? The only way I can get this to work is to put log4j.xml on the classpath.

passing: -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///c:\log4j2.xml on the command line doesn't work (although it does in a non spring-boot test application just fine).

I also tried putting this as an environment variable/property in spring.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to put this line into your `application.properties`:

```
logging.config=file:log4j.xml
```

Second option is to pass system variable to `-Dlogging.config=file:log4j.xml`

In this case it is expected to be located in current directory outside of the JAR file.

Comment: is there no way to put this outside of the jar?

c:\HOME\workspace\LibConfigSearchService\build\libs>java -jar myproject-0.0.1-SN
APSHOT.jar -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///c:\log4j2.xml

Comment: ok, if you want to change it from commond line than change `log4j.configuration` to `logging.config`

Comment: ok.. but I want it outside, your logging config should never be inside the runnable artifact (imo).

--logging.config.file=fie:///c:\log4j2.xml works. Thanks!

Comment: yes, I was using it with LobBack outside of the jar. Inside a jar was located application.properties file I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

you must put the "-Dlog4j" before the "-jar XXXX.jar".i try it my own .work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gradle, and trying to run a test method you will have to add following to the build.gradle. This enables the test method to pick -Dlog4j.configurationFile= to be picked during the test run :

test {
systemProperty "log4j.configurationFile", System.getProperty("log4j.configurationFile")
}