# How to set Spring log4j property file path programmatically

Tags: java, spring, log4j, spring-boot

I am using spring-boot this way;

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfiguration.class);
```

////

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.mycompnay")
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")})

public class SpringConfiguration {


    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
```

I am trying to understand how I can set the log4j.properties file this way? I found a way to do it with application.properties. but how we set it programatically for log4j.properties ?

log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, console

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.conversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - <%m>%n

#Debug logging
log4j.appender.DebugAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DebugAppender.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.DebugAppender.File=vertx.log
log4j.appender.DebugAppender.MaxFileSize=200KB
log4j.appender.DebugAppender.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.DebugAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.DebugAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - <%m>%n

log4j.logger.org.springframework=ERROR,console
log4j.logger.org.apache=ERROR,console
```

However on console I still see such loggings:

```
13:41:59.525 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
```

Added log4j debug. console output:

```
log4j: Reading configuration from URL file:/Users/idan/IdeaProjects/myservice-service/web/build/resources/main/log4j.properties
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[INFO, console].
log4j: Level token is [INFO].
log4j: Category root set to INFO
log4j: Parsing appender named "console".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "console".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d %p [%c] - <%m>%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "console".
log4j: Parsed "console" options.
log4j: Parsing for [org.apache] with value=[ERROR, console].
log4j: Level token is [ERROR].
log4j: Category org.apache set to ERROR
log4j: Parsing appender named "console".
log4j: Appender "console" was already parsed.
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.org.apache=[null]
log4j: Parsing for [org.springframework] with value=[ERROR, console].
log4j: Level token is [ERROR].
log4j: Category org.springframework set to ERROR
log4j: Parsing appender named "console".
log4j: Appender "console" was already parsed.
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.org.springframework=[null]
log4j: Parsing for [io.netty] with value=[INFO, console].
log4j: Level token is [INFO].
log4j: Category io.netty set to INFO
log4j: Parsing appender named "console".
log4j: Appender "console" was already parsed.
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.io.netty=[null]
log4j: Parsing for [com.mycompany] with value=[DEBUG, console].
log4j: Level token is [DEBUG].
log4j: Category com.mycompany set to DEBUG
log4j: Parsing appender named "console".
log4j: Appender "console" was already parsed.
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.com.mycompany=[false]
log4j: Setting additivity for "com.mycompany" to false
log4j: Parsing for [org.neo4j.jdbc.level] with value=[DEBUG, console].
log4j: Level token is [DEBUG].
log4j: Category org.neo4j.jdbc.level set to DEBUG
log4j: Parsing appender named "console".
log4j: Appender "console" was already parsed.
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.org.neo4j.jdbc.level=[null]
log4j: Finished configuring.
```

Thank,
ray.

Comment: The best solution would be to set  log4j.configurationFile system property, e.g. using -D VM start parameter. Please note that lo4j configurtation has nothing to do wioth spring set-up (of which the application.properties are part). See also https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

Comment: But I cant use that param since I am embedding Spring libs inside my java main process. or am I wrong ??

Comment: You would start your main java process with the mentioned -D parameter.  It is irrelevant whether your main process uses spring libs or not.

Comment: so inside intelij at the VM options line I added: -Dlogging.config=log4j.properties and Dlogging.path=resources/log4j.properties I still see DEBUG 13:41:59.525 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence. check my question I edited it

Comment: And what was your expectation? You did disable DEBUG level in log4j.properties?  Could you add -Dlog4j.debug to see if your log4j property file gets read? Why do you use -Dlogging.config and -Dlogging.path and not -Dlog4j.configurationFile= ?

Comment: I did disable it and I still see them! why Do I see them if I disabled them. I am using now -Dlog4j.configurationFile same outcome. seems like the spring framework doesnt consider that log4j file while my app-code actually does.

Comment: check my question. added console output after enabling Dlog4j.debug

Comment: Seems like it ignores the -Dlog4j.configurationFile path and it goes to resources (which I got there also the same file and still same outcome - debug is not disabled on console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90993/discussion-between-michal-and-rayman).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding this param to the executable jar:

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:/path.to/log4j.properties
```

Comment: But thats the answer. Just added this line as the VM params

Comment: Sorry - this wasn't clear to me when I reviewed the question. Now after your edit it is fine.

Comment: This was not successful for me, but this answer was: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32357170/4107809