# Spring Boot - Loading a .properties file from WEB-INF/ folder

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot 1.3 application (deployed as .war) that needs to be able read a `.properties` file from the following location:

`WEB-INF/application.properties` (outside the classpath, but relative to the app root folder)

...as opposed to:

`WEB-INF/classes/application.properties`(inside the classpath, gets loaded automatically)

What worked in Spring Boot 1.3 was the following `@PropertySource` annotation:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource(value = {"WEB-INF/application.properties"})
public class MyApplication {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

It correctly fetched the `.properties` file relative to the app root. However that stops working after an update to Spring Boot 1.4.0.RC1.

Since then I've tried the following:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:../application.properties")
@PropertySource("file:WEB-INF/application.properties")
```

and also

```
spring.config.location=classpath:../
spring.config.location=file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/
spring.config.location=WEB-INF/application.properties
```

But haven't had any luck loading the .properties.

I'd normally put the `.properties` file inside the classpath, but in this case this is NOT an option due to the way our deployment works on a remote location.

I'd also prefer to not use an absolute path, as that'll be a nightmare to support with multiple customers.

Edit: Just to be clear - the `.properties` I'd like to read aren't located outside the JAR (in my case - WAR) file, but inside - just not on the classpath, but directly in the `WEB-INF/` folder where normally other resources (pages, images) would be.

Comment: Is it possible to put it outside the war? It will find ones outside a jar, not sure about wars though. See: [Externalized Configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Comment: Unfortunately not - the `/WEB-INF/conf/application.properties` location is a given.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spring boot log4j file external to jar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32356997/spring-boot-log4j-file-external-to-jar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this issue was caused by a bug with the SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper in Spring Boot 1.4.0.RC1: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6371

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in duplicate SO question:

Put this line into your `application.properties`:

```
logging.config=file:log4j.xml
```

Second option is to pass system variable to `-Dlogging.config=file:log4j.xml`

In this case it is expected to be located in current directory outside of the JAR file.

**REACTION ON COMMENT**:

If you are using WAR file, your main class is not used at all. So `PropertySource` annotation doesn't have any effect there.

Comment: As stated in the question, the `.properties` I'd like to read aren't located outside the JAR (in my case - WAR) file, but inside.

Answer (score 0):

If the `.properties` is packed in the `.war` file. Then you can try the following (assuming that the `WEB-INF` directory is located in the root of the `.war` file.

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/WEB-INF/conf/application.properties")
```

Comment: Thanks, tried that, but still getting the error: `class path resource [WEB-INF/conf/application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist`